# Reactive app help in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(

# Application title
titlePanel("Linear model DARP"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput('ycol', 'Select a resonse variable', names(df_ln)[c(12,13,14)],
              selected=names(df_ln)[[1]]),
  sliderInput(inputId = "area",
              "select the service region area(km^2):",
              min= 170,
              max= 8000,
              value=1001),
  sliderInput(inputId = "crit..peak",
              label="Choose Peak demand(Requests):",
              min=10,
              max=150,
              value=40),
  sliderInput(inputId ="Speed",
              label = "Please selct you average Speed(mph):",
              min=10,
              max=50,
              value = 15)
),


mainPanel(
  tableOutput("table"),
  h5('The data shows the fleetsize required for your selection of input variables')
   )
  )
)
 df_ln<-read.csv("F:/Project/Programme/ML/DAR Machine Learning TR Part 
 A/train_darp_ln.csv")
 server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- reactive({
renderTable({

Linearmodel_DARP<-lm(input$ycol~area+crit..peak+speed,data = df_ln)
new_demand<-data.frame(area=input$area,crit..peak=input$crit..peak,speed=input$Speed)

fleetsize<-predict(Linearmodel_DARP,newdata=new_demand)
round(exp(fleetsize),0)

    })
     })

         }

        # Run the application 
        shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please help me to apply reactively the linear model and predict the new response variable 
The prediction of the ycol data selected from sidebar should be shown on the render table And in my app I am not getting anything 
I am not getting any error but the predicted data as per the selection is not shown in the app

```
dput(head(df_ln))
structure(list(area = c(2217.7, 6537.4, 1705.5, 5634, 1260.5, 
4797.7), density = c(0.13753, 0.016826, 0.18469, 0.021477, 0.25862, 
0.027305), crit..CV = c(0.63954, 0.81437, 0.49909, 0.33935, 0.39148, 
0.17489), crit..peak = c(49L, 26L, 41L, 20L, 39L, 18L), TW = c(21L, 
47L, 54L, 48L, 17L, 41L), L = c(569L, 576L, 391L, 390L, 458L, 
392L), s = c(7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 2L), speed = c(18L, 26L, 20L, 
30L, 24L, 33L), circuity = c(1.3284, 1.1494, 1.4597, 1.2725, 
1.0486, 1.0792), cap = c(9L, 9L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 7L), mrt = c(1.5452, 
2.3743, 1.5962, 2.6065, 2.1278, 2.6228), veh = c(4.605170186, 
3.433987204, 4.718498871, 3.951243719, 4.060443011, 3.526360525
), veh.hrs = c(6.665569062, 5.523778231, 6.496186582, 5.71857256, 
5.816843267, 5.256713817), veh.km = c(9.555940819, 8.781874769, 
9.491918855, 9.119769942, 8.994897097, 8.753221378)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Plese provide the output of `dput(df_ln)` so that we can try with your data. Or `dput(head(df_ln))` if it's enough.

Comment: added the dput(head(df_ln))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two errors:

- `output$table <- reactive({renderTable......` -> remove the `reactive`.
- in `lm(input$ycol~.....`, the `input$ycol` is a character string, that cannot work; replace with `lm(df_ln[[input$ycol]] ~ ....`

After doing these two modifications, I get the following app. Is it what you want?

[image]

Comment: Thanks I got the output

Comment: Can you check how can we change the output name instead of data shown in the shiny interface? I mean can we write anything else instead of data in the output.How to do it?